# How should I store multiple sessions to a user with Redis?

Tags: redis

Assuming a user can have multiple sessions (JWT tokens). Would it be best to store a **hashet** of tokens where the key is the userId?

E.g `key: 1 -> hashet: "token1", "token2", "token3", "token4", "moretokens..."`

To then check if a token is valid I'd get the hashset, loop through it and try match a token?

Using a hashet would mean I'd be able to show user there current sessions.

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`SET`](http://redis.io/commands#set) to store the tokens: take user ID as key, and store token list into the `SET` (as value), which contains unique elements.

```
// insert single token
sadd userId token1

// insert multiple tokens
sadd userId token2 token3

// insert an existing token will fail
sadd userId token1

// check if a token is valid
sismember userId token1

// get all tokens of a user
smembers userId
```

Comment: This solution doesn't consider session lifetime. How to handle multi-sessions lifetime in redis set?

Comment: You can expire with REDIS

Comment: You cannot expire elements in a set, list, etc. you can only expire the key which is problematic if session should expire at different times

Answer (score 0):

Hashes would be the most efficient way to store the values, as you can store all of a users tokens under the user ID, and check for them directly using HGET, without needing to retrieve them all and loop through them.